# Is $a \circ b:=\gcd(a,b)$ a group for $a$, $b$ in the natural numbers without $0$?

Tags: group-theory

> Is $a \circ b:=\gcd(a,b)$ a group for $a$, $b$ in the natural numbers without $0$?

I already could show that it is associative and closed. My suspicion is that there is going something wrong with the Inverse or the Existence of a Neutral Element but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: Do your natural numbers include $0$? You are correct that you will have (at least one) problem, but exactly which problem(s) depend on exactly what "Natural numbers" means.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Depends on whether $0\in\mathbb{N}$ or not...

Comment: $e\circ a=a$ requires the setting $gcd(e,a)=a.$ This might be artificial, but it won't be forbidden. Then $a\circ (e\circ a)=a\circ a=a=(e\circ a).$ If it was a group, we could cancel $(e\circ a)$ and get $a=e.$ Or even shorter: $a\circ a=a\Longrightarrow a=e.$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Fair point, I assumed it wasn't the case. Then the inverse would be an issue.

Comment: There’s multiple problems here. The neutral element could be fixed by using $0$. But how about an inverse? A quite convincing argument: In a group $x\to ax$ is a bijection for each $a$. But it is clearly very easy so come up with pairs $a,b,c$ so that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)$.

Comment: If I understand Marius SL correctly we make a proof by Contradiction by assuming it were a Group but then it would follow that $e=a$ which is a Contradiction because $e$ must be universal. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma:** For any group $G$, the only idempotent of $G$ is the identity, $e$

*Proof:* Let $x^2=x$. Then $ex=x=x^2=xx$, so, multiplying on the right by $x^{-1}$, we have $e=x$. $\square$

Note that $1\circ 1=\gcd(1,1)=1$ and $2\circ 2=\gcd(2,2)=2$.

Comment: This is very elegenat ty

Comment: You're welcome, @Iwan5050.